# How to convert a single Image to MP4 Video?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

How to convert a single image to mp4 video.

For example, I need to play the same image for 20 seconds (duration will be dynamic)

I know it's possible with **ffmpeg**. I searched in google & SO but unfortunately, I am not able to find the correct tutorial.

I just want a correct direction.

Any comment or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Look into [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073336/how-to-combine-images-and-generate-a-mp4-file) if you already not .

Comment: @ADM thanks. I will check

Comment: Is it not suitable just to draw the image on the surface or even literally switch to an imageview temporarily. Do you definitely want to create a video for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 20 out.mp4
```

The `-t` option sets the time, in seconds.

Comment: how to pass the my image? bitmap or path?

Comment: File path. ffmpeg can also receive on stdin via pipe

Comment: Great answer, thank you!   Heres an example using file name:           ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 1.png -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 10 out.mp4

Comment: How does this work if I'd like to create a video that is _shorter_ than 1 whole second? Like, a half-second video? I get an "Invalid duration specification" error when I try to specify a fractional second.

Comment: Make sure you specified the time as a decimal number i.e. `-t 0.5` not `-t 1/2`

Answer (score -1):

You can always use any video edit like windows movie maker.
Just add the photo to a project change the duration to 20 seconds and export
And then you have a 20 second video file of one image